# Socket Events not broadcasting

Tags: sockets, cors

I am working on a canvas project where in multiple users can log in and scribble on the canvas and it reflects real time updates to all logged in users.However, when I log in with two users in different windows, the changes are not visible. Moreover I have added some log statements in the MouseUp,MouseDown, MouseMove function but those aren't visible when I draw something on canvas.

This is my front end code for the canvas function/component.

`

```
const Canvas = () => {
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
const fabricCanvasRef = useRef(null);
const socketRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
    fabricCanvasRef.current = fabricCanvas;

    fabricCanvas.isDrawingMode =true;
    fabricCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
    fabricCanvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'black';

    socketRef.current = io('http://localhost:8080');

    fabricCanvas.on('mouse:down', handleMouseDown);
    fabricCanvas.on('mouse:move', handleMouseMove);
    fabricCanvas.on('mouse:up', handleMouseUp);

    return () => {
        fabricCanvas.off('mouse:down', handleMouseDown);
        fabricCanvas.off('mouse:move', handleMouseMove);
        fabricCanvas.off('mouse:up', handleMouseUp);
        socketRef.current.disconnect();
    }
}, []);

const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    const {x, y} = event.pointer;
    console.log('Mouse down:', x, y);
    socketRef.current.emit('draw:start', {x, y});
};

const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    if(!fabricCanvasRef.current.isDrawingMode) return;
    const {x, y} = event.pointer;
    console.log('Mouse move:', x, y);
    socketRef.current.emit('draw:progress', {x, y});
};

const handleMouseUp = () => {
    console.log('Mouse up');
    socketRef.current.emit('draw:end');
};

return (
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={800} height={600}></canvas>
)
```

}
`

The backend part of CORS and event broadcasting respectively

`    const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
cors: {
origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
credentials: true,
methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
}
});

`

`io.on('connection', (socket) => { console.log(`User ${socket.user.username} with ID ${socket.user.id} is connected`);

```
socket.on('draw:start', ({ x, y }) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('draw:start', { x, y });
    console.log("draw:start event broadcasted")
});

socket.on('draw:progress', ({ x, y }) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('draw:progress', { x, y });
    console.log("draw:progress event broadcasted")

});

socket.on('draw:end', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('draw:end');
    console.log("draw:end event broadcasted")

});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.user.username} with ID ${socket.user.id} disconnected`);
});
```

});

const port = 8080;
server.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Websocket server listening on port ${port}`);
});

`